# After installing Minecraft, I cannot figure out how to start the game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I installed Minecraft 1.7.2 and after installation it showed the launcher, and I played the game successfully.

But after I closed it, I realized there's no shortcut for Minecraft on the desktop, and when I go to my .minecraft folder and try to run anything there (such as launcher.jar, or 1.7.2.jar) none will open and nothing happens.

How do I start Minecraft?

Comment: It's probably in your downloads folder. Can you check there?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is the computer equivalent of misplacing your socks and asking us to help you find it.

Comment: I don't think so, the minecraft installer is supposed to create a desktop shortcut but it didn't.

Comment: @PrivatePansy [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote. Please don't use it as one.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one)

Comment: @Ender Questions about misplaced socks would be off topic on any site on the SE network.

Comment: @PrivatePansy, et al. - This question isn't worded the greatest, but it is, in fact, a very common misunderstanding with how Minecraft is installed and run.  Not understanding the launcher is the launcher and not an installation program is not equivalent to misplacing socks.  It's equivalent to thinking shoes are socks.

Comment: @JasonBerkan if you think this can be saved to actually be useful to the internet at large, I'd *highly* encourage you to edit it into that state. As it is, I stand by my downvote, and regret that I have but one to give.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - Downvote away.  It should **not** be closed.

Answer (score 8):

Minecraft does not "install" like a usual program (in fact, `Minecraft.exe` is not an *installer*). When started, it creates and uses a folder for itself (`.minecraft`), which contains the `*.jar` executables and assets, but it doesn't create a new launcher executable that is registered in the OS somewhere.

Minecraft is launched through the `Minecraft.exe` file you originally downloaded (and is probably in a `Downloads` folder somewhere, or whatever you picked as the download directory), which then runs the `.minecraft/launcher.jar` archive in java.

I recommend moving (and, if necessary, downloading again) the `Minecraft.exe` to a "safe" directory (say, making a new `Program Data/Mojang/Minecraft` directory and placing it there, or moving it to the `.minecraft` directory itself) and then making a shortcut to it on the Desktop. Minecraft will not do this on its own, as I described above.

Answer (score 4):

Minecraft launcher won't create a shortcut by default. You can find the launcher in your downloads folder. To find your downloads folder, check your browser settings.

Comment: It should though, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To find any application on Windows Vista/7/8 and above, you can also follow these steps:

1. Press the Start button on your keyboard (between Ctrl and Alt, to the left of the spacebar)
2. Immediately after pressing it, start typing the name of what you are looking for (e.g. "Minecraft"
3. You should see the application appear as a search result. Click it (or select with arrow keys and press Enter) to launch the application.