# Minecraft used by two users on same desktop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My sons share a minecraft account. On our desktop they have their own users. How do I make minecraft accessible from both user accounts? Do I need to download it for each user? Or can I somehow import it from the admin user to their users? They aren't looking for their own minecraft ID, just access through their own PC user account rather than having to go through mine.

Comment: @Vemonus That is not a duplicate. That question is asking about Minecraft accounts - this question is asking how to make the Minecraft application accessible on multiple Windows accounts. (You can argue whether that is actually gaming-related or not.)

Comment: @MageXy They're both asking how to use the same account for multiple people on the same PC though

Comment: @Vemonus In the end, I think Jennifer is asking how to create a desktop shortcut to Minecraft on multiple Windows accounts. While the topic is touched on in the other question in the comments, it's not explicitly answered.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/153339/145980) (and the top answer in particular) has the answer you need. Basically just take the Minecraft.exe file and put it on the desktop of both users.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the [minecraft.exe](https://launcher.mojang.com/download/Minecraft.exe) from [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/en/download/alternative) and move it to an independent location (like `C:/program files/minecraft/`) and place a link there on both Desktops or copy it to both Desktops directly.

To make a link just right-click the file and click on `send to...` - `Desktop`

Either way you can now start Minecraft with both user accounts (and still have the possibility for different resource packs and/or settings).

Answer (score 1):

The "account specific data" are saved in appdata, which exist per windows user. If they each have a different windows user, they can both run the game and have seperate accounts and savefiles.

Install the game on a location they both can access (like D:\Files\Minecraft) and you're done.